# syslog-ng 2.0.9 closing tcp connections from some clients instantly..?

Tags: solaris, tcp, syslog, connections

I've a syslog-ng instance on 2.0.9, which is old, but... this is enterprise IT and upgrading the versions is... fun... running on Solaris 10. I have this strange problem where some clients stop being able to stay connected to the server on TCP.

When a client is working I can start syslog-ng on the client, it connects and sends data, and STAYS connected...

```
12:20:13.200547 IP (tos 0x0, ttl  64, id 13064, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 60) 10.37.128.185.35765 > 10.37.141.31.shell: S, cksum 0xade4 (correct), 1572869826:1572869826(0) win 5840 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 958735818 0,nop,wscale 7>
12:20:13.202279 IP (tos 0x0, ttl  63, id 27707, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 64) 10.37.141.31.shell > 10.37.128.185.35765: S, cksum 0x434d (correct), 3180100791:3180100791(0) ack 1572869827 win 32942 <nop,nop,timestamp 2210148518 958735818,mss 1460,nop,wscale 2,nop,nop,sackOK>
12:20:13.202327 IP (tos 0x0, ttl  64, id 13065, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 52) 10.37.128.185.35765 > 10.37.141.31.shell: ., cksum 0x0499 (correct), ack 1 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 958735820 2210148518>
12:20:13.202823 IP (tos 0x0, ttl  64, id 13066, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 140) 10.37.128.185.35765 > 10.37.141.31.shell: P, cksum 0x179d (correct), 1:89(88) ack 1 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 958735820 2210148518>
12:20:13.204061 IP (tos 0x0, ttl  63, id 27708, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 52) 10.37.141.31.shell > 10.37.128.185.35765: ., cksum 0x83d6 (correct), ack 89 win 32920 <nop,nop,timestamp 2210148518 958735820>
12:20:13.205558 IP (tos 0x0, ttl  64, id 13067, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 124) 10.37.128.185.35765 > 10.37.141.31.shell: P, cksum 0xc071 (correct), 89:161(72) ack 1 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 958735823 2210148518>
12:20:13.206247 IP (tos 0x0, ttl  63, id 27709, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 52) 10.37.141.31.shell > 10.37.128.185.35765: ., cksum 0x839d (correct), ack 161 win 32902 <nop,nop,timestamp 2210148518 958735823>
```

When a client is failing to stay connected, I see the server instantly disconnecting with a FIN...

```
12:20:02.441949 IP (tos 0x10, ttl  64, id 8231, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 60) 10.37.128.185.46121 > 10.37.141.31.shell: S, cksum 0xeb7e (correct), 1553390564:1553390564(0) win 5840 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 958725059 0,nop,wscale 7>
12:20:02.443817 IP (tos 0x0, ttl  63, id 27678, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 64) 10.37.141.31.shell > 10.37.128.185.46121: S, cksum 0xe379 (correct), 3007391908:3007391908(0) ack 1553390565 win 32942 <nop,nop,timestamp 2210147442 958725059,mss 1460,nop,wscale 2,nop,nop,sackOK>
12:20:02.443840 IP (tos 0x10, ttl  64, id 8232, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 52) 10.37.128.185.46121 > 10.37.141.31.shell: ., cksum 0xa4c5 (correct), ack 1 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 958725061 2210147442>
12:20:02.445689 IP (tos 0x0, ttl  63, id 27679, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 52) 10.37.141.31.shell > 10.37.128.185.46121: F, cksum 0x2444 (correct), 1:1(0) ack 1 win 32942 <nop,nop,timestamp 2210147442 958725061>
12:20:02.445737 IP (tos 0x10, ttl  64, id 8233, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 52) 10.37.128.185.46121 > 10.37.141.31.shell: F, cksum 0xa4c1 (correct), 1:1(0) ack 2 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 958725063 2210147442>
12:20:02.447244 IP (tos 0x0, ttl  63, id 27680, offset 0, flags [DF], proto: TCP (6), length: 52) 10.37.141.31.shell > 10.37.128.185.46121: ., cksum 0x2441 (correct), ack 2 win 32942 <nop,nop,timestamp 2210147442 958725063>
```

Now this issue was originally seen to be on different clients, but in this case it's the ery same box. I generated the successful messages by restarting the client syslog-ng service and the unsuccesful ones from a telnet to the server port.

I've also started a new instance of the syslog-ng server on a different port, and on localhost a telnet to 514 connects and disconnects...

```
 $ telnet localhost 514
 Trying 127.0.0.1...
 Connected to localhost.
 Escape character is '^]'.
 Connection to localhost closed by foreign host
```

but on the other port, on a new process we get a connection left open nicely...

```
 $ telnet localhost 1140
 Trying 127.0.0.1...
 Connected to localhost.
 Escape character is '^]'.
 ^]
 telnet
 quit
 Connection to localhost closed.
```

So something in syslog-ng or in Solaris 10 appears to take a disliking to SOME of these connections after an undefined period of time of the process running. This is linked against tcpwrappers, with "syslog-ng:    ALL" defined in hosts.allow, and the behaviour i'm seeing looks similar to that which would happen if tcpwrappers was preventing the connection I think, but I don't think that that IS the part of the system at fault, as it seems to generic.

the "localhost to new process" behaviour *looks* to be the same as the remote connections, it doesn't look like a firewall getting in the way doing strange things or anything. And I'm lost.

Any guesses, pointers appreciated!

Comment: Do the logs on the syslog server give you anything interesting? And do you have any limit on number of clients?

Comment: Ahhhhh, that looks like it. it appears there's a default of 10 connections by default! What a bizzarly low number! Thanks

Comment: Cool, I've made it into an answer now. I'd appreciate if you'd accept it; it may help others later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `max-connections` setting in syslog.conf - it defaults to 10, which is probably too low for you.